# GPS for WiFi only MiPad

Tags: gps

I have a MiPad which works only with WiFi. How do I use it as a GPS device? Google map isn't able to access my location and my MiPad doesn't support tethering.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on MIUI website [here](http://en.miui.com/thread-33725-1-1.html):

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

> **Prerequisites:**
>
> 1. Have a device that has **GPS built-in** and **tethering/hotspot**.  In my case, I'm using the Xiaomi Mi 3.
> 2. Download and **install TetherGPS** Lite on both the Xiaomi Mi 3 and Xiaomi Mi Pad.
>
> **How it works:**
>
> 1. In the Xiaomi Mi Pad, **enable** Settings-Developer Options-**Allow mock locations**.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 2. **GPS location** must be **enabled** on both devices.
>
>    [image: IMG:] [image: IMG:]
> 3. On the **Xiaomi Mi 3**, enable Settings-Wireless & networks-Tethering & portable hotspot-**Portable hotspot**.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 4. On the **Xiaomi Mi Pad**, enable Settings-WLAN and I **connect to my Xiaomi Mi 3 hotspot**.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 5. **Start TetherGPS** on both devices.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 6. On the **Xiaomi Mi 3**, click on **Start Server**.
> 7. On the **Notifications bar**, you will see the **IP of the TetherGPS Server**.  Note it down.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 8. You will also see that your device will be searching for the location until it is found.
> 9. On your **Xiaomi Mi Pad**, click on **Start Client**.
>
>    [image: IMG:]
> 10. Under the **Notifications bar**, if you find that **TetherGPS Client is not working**, go into the TetherGPS app.  **Uncheck "Automatic Broadcast IP" and key in the IP** you noted down earlier.  Click on **"Stop Client"** and on **"Start Client"** again.
>
>     [image: IMG:]
> 11. If the setup is working, you will notice that both **Notifications** bar will **show the connection time of TetherGPS**.
> 12. Start your **Google Maps** or any **other navigation apps** and enjoy **driving from point A to point B** using your **big 7.9"** screen.

Comment: Hi! I added the images from that thread. They are important, so I believe they mustn't be left behind. Please make sure of this fact from the next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for one of your problem is here .
You can enable hotspot on your MI Pad

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=w0DLbEnHspw

Yes you can do it.

Ie is what you want if you use xender, interconnected games or shareit.

Have a happy time from here after